# Centralizing Package Imports in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, import, flutter-packages

In my Flutter project, I'm using around 10 different packages from `pub.dev`, which are required in multiple files such as `main.dart` and `home.dart` etc. To avoid redundant imports and keep my code organized, I tried centralizing all the package imports in a single file, say `app_imports.dart`. My idea was to import all the packages there and then import `app_imports.dart` in other files where I need those packages.

However, I encountered an issue where the imported packages in `app_imports.dart` were not being recognized in the other files, even though I imported `app_imports.dart` correctly.

So I am wondering if is it possible to centralize package imports in this manner in Flutter? If yes, what might be causing the issue I encountered? And what would be the correct way to achieve this centralization of imports to avoid importing the same packages in multiple files?

Any guidance or insights on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can you include the `app_imports`

Comment: Are you `export`ing all the packages you've included in `app_imports.dart`?